# Regex to replace empty value in a csv string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with value

```
 "ABC","ONE", "Hello",,,"2019"
```

I want to replace two consecutively empty values in a CSV file with `*`.

Expected output:

```
 "ABC","ONE", "Hello","*","*","2019"
```

This is what I tried,

```
line.replaceAll(",,","\"*\"");
```

But this gives me below output, replacing on first occurrence

```
"ABC","ONE", "Hello","*","2019"
```

Comment: What is your Actual output and what strings have you tried so far?

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex with lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=,)(?=,)
```

And replace it with `"*"`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eTx5Yc/2)

**Java Code:**

```
repl = str.replaceAll("(?<=,)(?=,)", "\"*\"");
```

Comment: I need "*" within quotes, ```"ABC","ONE", "Hello","*","*","2019"```

Comment: this worked for me ```line.replaceAll("(?<=,)(?=,)", "\"*\"");```. Thank you so much

Comment: @anubhava, Hello Anubhava sir, how about if we directly give `,,` to replace will it cause any problems if we give this in replacement sir? Could you please help to understand it sir.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13; No we cannot avoid lookahead/ and/or lookbehind here. If you take `,,,` as input and replace `,,` with `,"*",` then it will replace only first 2 commas leaving 3rd one intact.